# Dump of SQL Server insert data

Tags: sql-server-2005, dump

Is there a free tool that will allow you to dump the data (not the structure) of an MS-SQL Express (2005) table as INSERT statements to a flat file?

[This](http://www.sqlmaestro.com/products/sqlite/maestro/help/05_05_00_sql_dump/) commercial product seems to do what I have in mind. I've tried using [SqlDump](http://sqldump.sourceforge.net/) but my full server name will not fit in its SQL Server Name field.

Comment: if you can search in this blog http://blog.sqlauthority.com/, i think you can find a tool that does what you want. it helps me, about some months ago...

Answer (score 4):

What you need to do is

1. Right click on your database in management studio
2. select tasks -> generate scripts
3. Choose table you want data from
4. in next step click advanced and set "types of data to script" set to data only (or whatever you need)

works with sql serfver 2008 r2.
in previous versions of sql server its something like "Script data" which you set to true.

Answer (score 2):

tablediff is a free tool that comes with MS SQL Server.  As long as your source is the table that you want to generate inserts from, and you've got another empty table that you want to generate inserts to, it'll create exactly the file that you're looking for.

BCP is probably the better choice of a utility for moving data - but it won't generate the actual DML insert statments like it sounds you're looking for.

I'd also check out the Database Publishing Wizard.  I've not used this, but it should be able to script both your schema and data - and from there you could cut up the scripts that it generates to be what you're looking for.

See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162843.aspx) for more info on the tablediff utility.

See [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=56E5B1C5-BF17-42E0-A410-371A838E570A&displaylang=en) for the download of the database publishing wizard.

Answer (score 1):

I think [This](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/code/generate_inserts.txt) will work for you, but you'll have to run it for each table.

Comment: I get the feeling he doesnt have a way to get in to Sql Express (No GUI)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not what you had in mind, and the tools suggested look promising but if the data is going from one SQL Server to another, a low overhead alternative would be using [bcp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802(SQL.90).aspx). Important options below include the -E for retaining identity info, and the -n for using native format. Executing the first statement would let build a batch file to dump all the data to file, the second statement will create the bcp ins.

```
Select 'bcp ' + Table_Catalog  + '..' + 
Table_Name + ' out ' + Table_Name 
+ '.bcp  -S ServerName -U userid -P password -n '
from information_schema.tables 
where table_type = 'BASE TABLE'

Select 'bcp ' + Table_Catalog  + '..' + Table_Name 
+ ' in .\' + Table_name + 
'.bcp  -S .\ -U userid -P password -n -E '
from information_schema.tables 
where table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
```

Sample output

bcp out command

```
bcp master..tblDepartments out tblDepartments.bcp  -S ServerName -U
userid -P password -n
```

bcp in command

```
bcp master..tblDepartments in .\tblDepartments.bcp  -S .\ 
-U userid -P password -n -E
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it http://sourceforge.net/projects/vwg-ent-man

Answer (score 0):

try the free [SSMS Tools Pack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/) which is an add-in for SSMS and SSMS Express. it enables you to generate insert scripts for a table, dte whole database or just for the query results.